# Custom Login Form - Redirect user to login page if not logged in

Tags: redirect, login, authentication

I have integrated custom login form as mentioned [here](http://designmodo.com/wordpress-custom-login/) and embed this custom login form to a WordPress page, via shortcode `[dm_login_form]`.

After that I have integrated access control plugin [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-access-control/) which allows me to redirect user to login page if not logged in.

I need to redirect user to my custom login page whenever a blog `post/page` is accessed by a `non-authenticated` user. It goes into redirect loop if I provide my custom login page `URL`.

For admin authentication I am using default `wp-login.php`  URL while other users login using custom login page `URL`.

Code in functions.php for redirection

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_user');

function redirect_user(){
    global $current_user;
    if (!is_user_logged_in()){
        $return_url = site_url().'/login';
        wp_redirect($return_url);
        exit();
    }
}
```

I just need to redirect user to my login page URL if hes not logged in and try to access any page/post. How can I prevent this redirect loop ?

Thanks.

Comment: add `exit;` just after `wp_redirect($return_url);`.

Comment: @Roberthue, question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function to redirect non-users to login page.

```
function redirect_user() {
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page( 'login' ) ) {
    $return_url = esc_url( home_url( '/login/' ) );
    wp_redirect( $return_url );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_user' );
```

Comment: Using the code, when I try to access `contact-us/` page, it goes into redirect loop.

Comment: Maybe `if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page( 'login' ) )` will avoid the redirect loop.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy make sure page slug is correct.

Comment: @birgire made changes in code to avoid redirection loop to login page. :) Thanks

Comment: @Roberthue may be plugin `WordPress Access Control Settings` is redirecting it to default wp-login page, overriding the code. If the defult login url is changed from plugin settings then it goes to redirect loop.